What are these metal things from the roof that the roofers left behind?
Roofers redid our roof recently, and they left behind these 3 metal things in our back yard.
Any idea what those three metal things are?
And I assume I don't need to keep them, right?


Type of roof you have might help.  I have something similar, but they are made from 1/4 inch steel and are bases for curved steel tubes holding up the tarp.  If holes in the base, maybe ventilation/drainage.

Do save the extra bundles of shingles somewhere. They will be the closest thing to matching your roof if there is ever minor damage in the future. They won't match exactly after a few years (as they will be unweathered) but they will be the right color and pattern; and you already paid for them...

They are roof vent boots. They go over the vents that go through your roof and then are sealed under your shingles or roof tiles. These are made of lead and the tops are bent down into the actual top of the vent to prevent water from dripping down the outsides of the pipe. The roofers probably left them so you'd know they were replaced with new ones. You can discard them.

Probably best to send them to a scrapyard that can deal with non-ferrous metal vs. tossing them in general garb age btw

They have monetary value as lead scrap, and environmental negative value as garbage, so yes, scrap them, don't bin them.

Thanks. Where I live there are scrap trucks that comb our alleys, so I will leave them out and I expect they'll be taken
